# Upgrading Ubuntu 15.10 to Xenial Xerus

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, 15.10, update-manager

I currently have Ubuntu 15.10 and I want to upgrade that to Xenial Xerus ( 16.04 LTS ),

I invoked this in terminal :

```
update-manager -d
```

but when the windows pops out and it downloads some files from repository
it says :

```
The software on this computer is up to date
```

It doesn't find 
the new release

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks I fixed it with adding a sudo before the command. The problem was about permission...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sudo` to the command to run it as an administrator for `update-manager` to work properly. So you would run `sudo update-manager -d`. Rule of thumb: If  a command modifies your system, it needs `sudo`.